# how to get the value of the key without looping through in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a for loop in which I need to assign the value of the new key taking from another dictionary. I am trying to avoid for loop in for loop. My first dictionary looks like the following:

```
ids = [{'1020': 'ID-2522'}, {'1030': 'ID-2523'}, {'1040': 'ID-2524'}]
```

The list of dictionaries I am looping through looks like the following:

```
data = [{'sf_id': '1020', TotalPrice': '504'}, {'sf_id': '1030', TotalPrice': '400'}, {'sf_id': '1040', TotalPrice': '500'}]
```

Here is my for loop:

```
for index, my_dict in enumerate(data):
    for key, value in my_dict.items():
         new_id = my_dict["sf_id"]
         opportunity = ids[new_id]
```

So that it grabs the correspondent value. Desired output would be:

```
print(opportunity)
ID-2522
ID-2523
ID-2524
```

Comment: You ids is a list and not dict

Comment: the list of dictionaries. Doesn't change the fact.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no duplicates key in the entire collection you can use [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) to merge every id dict into a single dict of ids so you only iterate both collections just once

```
from functools import reduce

ids = [{'1020': 'ID-2522'}, {'1030': 'ID-2523'}, {'1040': 'ID-2524'}]
data = [{'sf_id': '1020', 'TotalPrice': '504'}, {'sf_id': '1030', 'TotalPrice': '400'}, {'sf_id': '1040', 'TotalPrice': '500'}]

ids_map = reduce(lambda x, y: x.update(y) or x , ids, {})

for my_dict in data:
  new_id = my_dict["sf_id"]
  opportunity = ids_map[new_id]
  print(opportunity)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there might be.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in @mad_'s comment, `ids` is a list of dicts, not a dict. This makes looking up one of the keys very inefficient, as you would have to go through the whole list to find it.

So, the first step is to merge all of these small dicts into a large one.

Then, we can efficiently build a list with your expected output:

```
ids = [{'1020': 'ID-2522'}, {'1030': 'ID-2523'}, {'1040': 'ID-2524'}]

data = [{'sf_id': '1020', 'TotalPrice': '504'}, 
        {'sf_id': '1030', 'TotalPrice': '400'}, 
        {'sf_id': '1040', 'TotalPrice': '500'}]

ids_dict = {k:v for dct in ids for k, v in dct.items()}

opportunity = []

for my_dict in data:
    new_id = my_dict["sf_id"]
    opportunity.append(ids_dict[new_id])

print(opportunity)
# ['ID-2522', 'ID-2523', 'ID-2524']
```

(Note that you don't need `enumerate` if you don't use the index)

Or, shorter, with a list comprehension:

```
opportunity = [ids_dict[my_dict["sf_id"]] for my_dict in data]
print(opportunity)
#  ['ID-2522', 'ID-2523', 'ID-2524']
```

Comment: If I change the keys in ids then it still returns the same data, which is wrong, I need it to return only the values that are associated with the specific key, so let's say if there is no 1020 value for sf_id key, then it shouldn't return ID-2522... If I change `sf_id` from 1020 to 1234 it does return ID-2522.

Comment: It doesn't, it gives a KeyError. If some id might be missing from `ids`, you should make that clear in your question.

Comment: Replaced all the keys and it returns the same result. Not a keyError

Comment: You didn't copy the whole code, you forgot `ids_dict = {k:v for dct in ids for k, v in dct.items()}` and used the version created with your first data, so you got the old result. Do it correctly and you'll get `KeyError: 1020`.

Answer (score -2):

```
# Create a new variable and save sftoap in it
new_ids = ids

# pop the items from original list of dicts and save it in a new dict 
sftoap_dict = {}
for d in new_ids:
    key, value = d.popitem()
    sftoap_dict[key] = value
```